# Can a warg control dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35309/19836) about *Game of Thrones* it is asked if the White Walkers can reanimate dragons and control them. The answer postulates that dragons might burn up upon death. It also posits that dragons are, in fact, animals.

This got me to wondering if wargs are able to control dragons. Since Bran is a warg, and a powerful one at that (he was able to control Hodor), would he be able to control Daenerys' dragons?

Comment: Speculation.  This is an acceptable question?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Sometimes you don't know if there is no definitive answer until you ask the question. I haven't read the books. Often there's an answer in the books that wasn't on-screen

Comment: We really only deal with the TV/Film content... yes, we have people who have read the books but if you really want a book-based answer, you're probably better served asking on SFF. I don't usually direct people there with overlap questions but we're not specialists in the books, we're specialists in the show.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Speculation is not generally acceptable but, while we may be unable to answer this question now, it may easily be answerable three seasons from now... or not... The question doesn't seem to be asking for people to guess, just asking if it's possible at all which, from the content we have, it's not possible to answer.

Comment: @Catija I'm asking about the show. Sometimes the book fleshes things out that are only glossed over in the show. And sometimes I just missed something in the show. ...and sometimes the correct answer is, "we don't know." Somebody had a pretty well written answer on here but I guess a mod nixed it because I'm only seeing one answer now

Comment: Please don't blame mods for assumptions. The person who posted the answer self-deleted it. In fact, one of the mods has asked the person why they deleted it because it seemed like a good answer.

Comment: Anyway, the point of my comment was that your comment above seemed to specifically want content from the book... that's not in your question, so it's fine... We like questions here and don't want to discourage you from asking.

Comment: Related question that can't yet be answered: was Hodor a warg target because of the brain damage he suffered, and therefoe other sentient beings are *not* warg targets, or is it just harder to warg into a more sentient beings, and therefore could Bran become powerful enough to warg into any human, and how sentient/smart are dragons, actually?

Comment: @ToddWilcox re: Hodor could be answered with the books.

Comment: @ToddWilcox http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33068/can-brandon-only-control-hodor

Comment: @Catija Sorry, Didn't mean to blame the mods. It occurred to me the poster may have deleted themselves after I sent the message. Oh, I see they put it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently this is speculation as there is actually still relatively little details known about both warging and dragons, but it seems unlikely even if it were 'physically' possible.

- It has shown that warging can be done relatively easily if a positive  bond exists between the Warg and the subject, e.g. Bran warging in Summer. So in this case it might be possible. However, there is the question why a dragon would allow this invasive thing as they can take intelligent actions by themselves and it seems unlikely that they need the added human intellect to guide them.
- If no bond exists and it is involuntary, it comes down to a battle of wills and based on what we've seen in books and show it seems the warg is at a disadvantage as the 'intruder' so can typically only control weaker-minded wills. Dragons have been shown to be intelligent and strong-willed. So you'd need one incredibly strong Warg. Maybe not impossible but very unlikely.

Note that there is a good chance this remains unanswered. G.R.R.M tends to keep a hint of mysticism over how all magical things in this world work and the show seems to follow that relatively well. So unless a Warg actually controls a dragon I doubt we'll know.

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to glean from the show how warging works. So far they haven't shown anyone or anything attempt to resist the warg as has appoarently occurred in the books. I guess we'll have to wait and see if anyone tries to control a dragon by warging

Answer (score 8):

At this time, there has been no instance of a warg or greenseer jumping into a dragon in the books, or the show which has now surpassed the books. Anything else is speculation.

Comment: On top of that, I can't even think of anything that someone would interpret as a clue to answer this question. Wargs and dragons just haven't interacted in any way or even been discussed in the same conversation.