# Why did Bran not warg into Drogon?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

It is seen that Bran can control any living things with some magic power in Game of Thrones. We have also seen once he had controlled one of the dragons during the battle at Winterfell with the Night King which implies that he could have controlled Drogon but he did not.

Was Drogon too powerful to control or did Bran play a trick to become the King of the six kingdoms?

Comment: Can you mention when you saw Bran controlling a dragon?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53879/can-a-warg-control-dragons

Comment: https://www.inverse.com/article/55943-game-of-thrones-season-8-finale-spoilers-bran-warge-daenerys

Comment: In the last we see of Bran, isn't that what he meant by "perhaps I can find him" or whatever he said to that effect?

Comment: @Samual Is the article you linked on inverse.com your only source for Bran controlling a dragon?

Comment: @krb, as JNat pointed out, in finale Bran said that he could find Dragon that also somehow implies that he might have a reach to Drogon.

Comment: Being able to find him implies nothing except being able to find him.  Bran needs only to step back the few weeks to when Drogon left and see which way he went, then keep stepping ahead in time along with Drogon until he reaches the present.

Comment: *"he had controlled one of the dragons during the battle at Winterfell"* - Wait, what? O_O

Comment: I think Bran had warg into Rhaegal to engage with Viserion. Although, there is no scientific proof of anything O_O_________

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bran went to look for Drogon.

> (BRAN) And Drogon? Any word?
>
> (SAM) He was last spotted flying east, toward--
>
> (BRONN) The farther away, the better.
>
> (BRAN) Perhaps I can find him. Do carry on with the
>   rest.
>
> (TYRION) As you wish, Your Grace.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Game Of Thrones, Season 8, Episode 6 (The Iron Throne)</sub>

This sounds like Bran will have to search for him in the body of some other being rather than warg straight into him. As mentioned [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53879/can-a-warg-control-dragons) it *might* be possible that he could control Drogon but unlikely seeing as Drogon probably wouldn't want to be controlled by anyone while he was mourning his mother/Queen.

Comment: This seems a fair answer to this question

Comment: Although this seems a satisfactory answer for me, it would be nice if few more throw more light on it.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to warg into a creature seems to depend somewhat on its mental capacity. For example we never see him warging into any person except for Hodor, whose mind is damaged.

So it is possible that he can't warg into a dragon because the dragons are too intelligent to be controlled that way.